# how can I add the left cell and the upper cell using a formula in microsoft excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to create a formula in microsoft excel to set the value of the cell which is the sum of the left cell and the upper cell?
any idea how to do it?

see below screenshot as an example, B2=A2 + B1, B3=A3 + B2, but I don't want to write a formula for each cell in column B one by one, any way to generate the formula automatically or is there any formula that works like "B1(or B2, B3...)=left() + upper()"

[image]

Comment: If you set one the value of the cell `B2` to `= A2 + B1` and then drag the bottom right corner of the cell, then drag the bottom right corner of the cell it will update the positions in the formula. `B3` for instance will get the value `= A3 + B2`. You have to use something like `A$1`, `$A1` or `$A$1` to force the row, column, or both to be absolute rather than relative when dragged. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I set B2=A2+B1, and dragged the bottom right corner of the cell, it worked fine. if no other solution, this is what I am looking for. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is lacking in specifics but perhaps that is what you need.

Select B2 and go to Formulas ► Defined Names ► Name manager. When the Name Manager dialog opens, click New. Provide a name (e.g. leftSum), use the worksheet you are operating on for the scope, add a comment to explain what you are doing if desired and supply the following for the **Refers to:** text:

```
=SUM(A2, B1)
```

Click OK to create the dynamic named range formula then Close to close the Name Manager dialog.

Go to any cell with numbers to the left/left-and-up and type in,

```
=leftSUM
```

[image: leftSunm2]

Comment: thanks for your answer, i added more information in the orignal post.

Comment: Just use the second formula I provided for the Refers to: parameter of hte named range.

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand what you want. You just want to add the value of the cell above with the value of the cell to the left. Try type this in cell B2:

`=B1+A2`

Then, click cell B2 and (since you are using MS Office 10) hover your mouse on the small black square in the bottom-right of the cell. Your mouse cursor should turn into a + sign. Then you can drag down to the lowest cell that you want to copy the formula to. Excel is 'smart' enough to automatically change the formula based on the first formula you typed in. You just have to drag and let go. The values should be updated.